# Batch Files Pull Variables from Text Document

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm in the process of remuxing a bunch of videos I have. Once I have them remuxed, they all have different audio offsets that I need to implement. I have a batch file that will go through every file in the folder and do one offset. However, I would like to have it go into a text document (Offsets.txt) and pull info from it.

This is my "Offsets.txt"

```
Bio Broly.mkv: +1.112450
Bojack Unbound.mkv: +1.034330
Broly Second Coming.mkv: -1.166504
Broly Legendary Super Saiyan.mkv: +1.3140975
Coolers Revenge.mkv: +.032810
Dead Zone.mkv: +0
Fusion Reborn.mkv: .944 Seconds
```

This is my "AV Sync Fix.bat"

```
@echo off
set /P Delay=What is the delay you would like to use?
set /P Track=What track would you like to change?
for %%i in (*.mkv) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o output/"%%i" -y %track%:%delay% "%%i"
Echo Your files were moved to a folder called output. Press ENTER to quit:
pause
Exit
```

I would like it to run that "for" command for each video line, filling in the delay automatically. I still want to manually put in the track.

Just to make sure I said it right. I want to start the batch file, still put in the track to change, then it will run the "for" command on each mkv file and use the corresponding delay for each. Whether I have 3 files, or 80 files. And it will only run on the files in that list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> And it will only run on the files in that list.

Okay, then you should enumerate the list, not `*.mkv`:

```
@echo off
set /P Track=What track would you like to change?
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%O in ("offsets.txt") do (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%%O") do (
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o output/"%%a" -y "%Track%:%%b" "%%a"
        echo:&echo:&echo:
    )
)
pause
```

**Sync offsets should be set in milliseconds** (see mkvmerge documentation) unless you want to have a headache dealing with floats via the limited batch-file integer arithmetic.

Comment: I was going to convert to milliseconds later. That is just my text document as I'm processing the video. As far as your code goes, thank you very much. I'm gonna try and understand it some more. Most of my coding experience is just copy and paste then tweak a little. I have no clue what you just gave me, what most of it means, or if it's even complete code or if I have more to do. Lol. So I'll take a look and see what I can do with it. Thanks again! PS. If you wouldn't mind breaking it down a little bit to explain things, I'd appreciate it. The I'll do my own research though.

Comment: Got it mostly figured out. That being said, still wouldn't appreciate some notes on the things.

Comment: The first `for /f` reads offsets.txt, `delims=` (nothing) means an entire line is read into %%O, `usebackq` makes it possible to use quotes around the file name in case it contains spaces ("some offsets.txt", for example). The second `for /f` splits the line at `:` into two tokens (`tokens=1,2`), the first `%%a` is a file name, the second `%%b` is a sync offset.

Comment: Thanks again! I've used it several times and it works great!